# How i can filter based on wildcards on mysql?

Tags: mysql, filter, wildcard

I have values like this on a table on a MySQL database:

- a) select ? from list ?
- b) select all from list
- c) select something from list ?

My idea is that if i have a string like "select age from list childs" it will select the row "a" and return "age" and "childs" as values.

Also if i get a string like "select something from list pets" it will select the row "c" and return "pets" as value (It match better with "c" than "a");

I tried with LIKE and %, but i failed. I googled a lot also, but i really don't know how to search what i'm looking for.

Edit: I'm using PHP, just in case some code is needed :D

Edit2: The strings are stored exactly like on the example, with the "?" included!

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: How are the question marks (?) used?

Comment: @ArtemKalinchuk
I used question marks, but they can be anything that symbolize "something goes here" (a wildcard).

Comment: Hmm...So you want a user to input their own value where the question marks are? If you're using PHP, you can try `"SELECT $fields from list $list"` and then set `$fields = ""; // either a column name or '*' for all` and `$list = ""; // whatever list (or table) you set`. Is this what you're looking for?

Edit: This is just an example. You should consider protecting against SQL injections.